# subdomain redirection

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, subdomain, virtualhost

I'd like to redirect all subdomains *.local to their sub dirs, for example:

```
test.local/ --> /files/test/data/
```

Here's my vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local
    ServerAlias *.local
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.local
    RewriteCond /files/%1/data -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /mv/$1/data
</VirtualHost>
```

The trouble is that's not working, I get a file not found error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While you've got more going on there in the mod_rewrite setup than just this, `VirtualDocumentRoot` may fill your needs?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local
    ServerAlias *.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot /files/%-2/data
</VirtualHost>
```

(the `%-2` specifies that the second to last name in the domain should be used; so for `www.test.local` and for `test.local`, `/files/test/data` will be used in both cases)